# Diisplay Rich text in ASP.NET Core (Razor)

Tags: asp.net, razor, tinymce, richtext

I have played around creating a restaurant site. I finally got tinyMCE to work, so that i can write text to my database using bold, italic etc.

However when i try to show the text, its not showing up in rich format, neither are images showing.

My code looks like this when i write it down:

```
<div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <label asp-for="MenuItem.Description" class="custom-label"></label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input id="mytextarea" asp-for="MenuItem.Description" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <span asp-validation-for="MenuItem.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

However, when i want to see the text, it returns like this:

[image]

This is the code for showing it:

```
<div class="form-border row">
    <div class="col-8">
        <fieldset disabled>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="MenuItem.Name" class="custom-label"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <input asp-for="MenuItem.Name" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-4">
                    <label asp-for="MenuItem.Description" class="custom-label"></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-8">
                    <textarea asp-for="MenuItem.Description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Is it my forms that somehow prevents me from showing the text in Rich format?

Edit: 
I've initialized my tinyMCE like this

```
<script>

    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#mytextarea',
        theme: 'modern',
        plugins: ['advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak',
            'searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen',
            'insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality',
            'emoticons paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools'
        ],
        toolbar1: 'insertfile undo redo | styleselect fontselect fontsizeselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image',
        toolbar2: 'print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons',
        image_advtab: true,
        height: "700",
        file_picker_callback: function (callback, value, meta) {
            if (meta.filetype === 'image') {
                $('#upload').trigger('click');
                $('#upload').on('change', function () {
                    var file = this.files[0];
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        callback(e.target.result, {
                            alt: ''
                        });
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                });
            }
        }

    });

</script>
```

As said, i can write it down just fine, and i have this bar when doing so:

[image]

Comment: You may need to initialize tinymce.
```tinymce.init({
    selector: '#IdOfTextArea'
  });```

Comment: Since it looks like you already have the content as HTML (not rich text), you can just display it but not inside a textarea, which doesn't natively support anything like that. Just do `@Html.Raw(MenuItem.Description)`- or initialize tinyMCE for the second textarea too if you want it editable.

Comment: @JustinE I've edited my original post.

Comment: @AlexPaven Where would i put the @Html.Raw(MenuItem.Description) ?

Comment: @AlexPaven I've tried to initialize it on my details view like you suggested and it worked like a charm, it shows images etc. However, I it is editable like you rightly said it would be.
But i I just need it to show the "Blog" with images, bold, italic etc, no edit and toolbar.
Sorry if its a noob question, but i really do feel like a noob at the moment :)

Comment: Output the raw html just in a `<div>` or something. So just replace your `<textarea>` with it I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to render the content (as opposed to edit it) you want to place it in something like a `div` and not a textarea.

Depending on your framework you may need to tell it not to escape the HTML (often done as a safeguard against attacks).